# Re-signing xcarchive file, but IPA does not install

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning, ad-hoc-distribution, codesign

A third-party-company has sent us an xcarchive file so that we can export their application as an IPA for our client. They've done this because we control our client's provisioning profiles and certificates. They don't have our certificates and keys and so cannot build a distribution version of the app.

I opened the xcarchive in Organizer and attempted to export an ad-hoc IPA using the client's Enterprise distribution provisioning profile. However, when I attempt to install the app on my iPad, the installation fails.

I've verified that I'm using the correct provisioning profile, and I checked to make sure that I have the correct certificate for the profile as well as the private key. I've never signed an app with this provisioning profile before, but I've used the certificate and key for other profiles.

From what I understand, re-signing an archive should be possible. I'm not sure why this isn't working, though. Does the third-party company need to do anything specific when they export the xcarchive file - do they need to build with a specific certificate or provisioning profile?

Any insight on this would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I can't help you as to why its not working but I know the 3rd party do not ned to do anything special, as I'm a 3rd party who supplies an app archive to another company and they strip off my credentials and re-sign it with their own. I just create an archive as part of an Xcode bot build and give it do them, doing nothing different nor special for them. Does the app bundle id match with the profiles being used to resign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to re-sign an ipa following the instructions found at this link: http://sholtz9421.wordpress.com/2012/06/08/digitally-resigning-ipa/.  However, I used Xcode to edit the plist, not emacs.

Comment: This actually worked for me. I'm not sure, but my hunch is that Xcode got confused as to which certificate to sign with (as I have two certs in my keychain with the same name, but different keys and expiration dates). Signing manually solved this.